# MIDI keyboard recognized on lsusb, but doesn't work

Tags: usb, sound, alsa, midi

The other day I decided I might try to make some music on Ubuntu 18.04.
I have a synthesizer that can work on its own, but it can also send an receive MIDI, namely a Novation MiniNova.
So I downloaded LMMS from the Software Store, created a tune in it without the use of the keyboard. Up until this point, no problems.

Now, when I plugged in my MiniNova, I expected to just run a few commands and be done with it. How wrong could I be. LMMS didn't recognize my keyboard, neither did KMidiMon. I followed [this guide](http://tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html) by a bloke named Ted and followed every step closely up until the point where I had to run `cat /proc/asound/cards` to figure out what ALSA named my sound card. I used `sox` to generate a 440 Hz sine .wav file, then I typed `aplay -D hw:1 test.wav` and I heard the sine wave through my laptops speakers.
`lsusb` gave me the MiniNova in the list, but adding the verbose option told me that it `Couldn't open the device, some information missing.`which seems weird to me.

I did come across a weird little thing when I decided that it couldn't hurt to run LMMS through a terminal. When I did, I got the following result:

```
ALSA lib rawmidi_hw.c:233:(snd_rawmidi_hw_open) open /dev/snd/midiC0D0 failed: No such file or directory
cannot open MIDI-device: No such file or directory
Couldn't create MIDI-client, neither with ALSA nor with OSS. Will use dummy-MIDI-client.
Connection established.

Stream successfully created

MidiClientRaw: unhandled MIDI-event 176

MidiClientRaw: unhandled MIDI-event 176

MidiClientRaw: unhandled MIDI-event 176
```

The last three messages were after opening the project I had been working on.

If it's helpful, here are links to my results after typing:

- [aplay -l](https://gist.github.com/WalrusGumboot/853db352d3964ca3ba2448134938bddb)
- [cat /proc/asound/cards](https://gist.github.com/WalrusGumboot/4c8beb9070a3cd5e80f35ab47f755d6b)

Thanks in advance,
WalrusGumboot

Comment: As far as I know, the MiniNova is not class compliant, i.e., it does not use a standard protocol, so the Linux driver does not yet support it. Please show the output of `sudo lsusb -v -d 1235:001e`.

Comment: @CL. Gotcha: https://gist.github.com/WalrusGumboot/5ab36729fd508aefad47f64e3b807c90

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not (yet) support this device; you have to [build your own kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel). You do not need to make any configuration changes, but instead edit the file `sound/usb/quirks-table.h`, and add the following entry anywhere:

```
{
    USB_DEVICE(0x1235, 0x001e),
    .driver_info = (unsigned long) & (const struct snd_usb_audio_quirk) {
        .ifnum = 0,
        .type = QUIRK_MIDI_RAW_BYTES
    }
},
```