# Does the latest Ubuntu version support a non-compliant keyboard?

Tags: usb, keyboard

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and in a Q&A

[MIDI keyboard recognized on lsusb, but doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140744/midi-keyboard-recognized-on-lsusb-but-doesnt-work)

it says that the non class compliant USB keyboard Novation Mininova is not "yet" in the Linux kernel drivery. Since that was in 2019, I'm wondering whether or not the 2023 situation is any different?

I've had issues with U 22.04, so I'm unable to test with e.g. that version, if the keyboard works already.

(The amateur-ish github alternatives to an "out of the box" solution do not work decently, so please do not waste your time suggesting those.

I have contacted the keyboard manufacturer, and it is unfortunate that there has been no straightforward Linux solution (i.e. no out of the box support) for a still manufactured, over a decade-old keyboard.)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Nothing for us to answer; you seem to be looking or opinions Not sure what you got against github but this https://github.com/nclavaud/mininova-web-editor  states you need a u-dev file and can use a browser for setup. Not that diffcicult. Plus don't call it just a keyboard. That has a diff. meaning. It is a "Synthesizer keyboard" Those need tools to get working. Also see https://nclavaud.github.io/mininova-web-editor/